# Copy/Migrate Services between same version ArcGIS Servers

Tags: arcgis-server

Before marking as duplicate, please note this migration is from same version servers.

I would like to migrate 200+ services from a development environment to a test environment in ArcGIS Server. Both servers have been installed and configured the same way and are on the same 10.2.2 version.

Is there any way I can batch migrate or copy the services over?

Comment: Do you have your source .mxd documents and GP results that have been used for publishing the services on the dev server? Or we are starting with no source data and having only the published services?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I do have the source MXD files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can go and it will likely be a combination of several ones.

**1** Use the [backup/restore site utility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Backup_utility/01540000065s000000/) installed with ArcGIS Server 10.2. This will create a backup of your services and all the server configuration. You can then restore the site on your test environment. There might be some issues with replacing the site machine as you are restoring it on another machine. This implies that you have all your services pointing to a shared location available from both machines. Never was able to make it work smoothly myself. Lots of people reported issues when going this way.

**2** Use Python and arcpy to go into each directory in `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput` and go into the `v101` folder within each service directory where you find the map document for which you will need to adjust the data path (if your services on the test machine will point to another location). You can parse either manifest.xml or manifest.json to find out what is the data source used for the map service. By knowing this, you edit each map document [data source path](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000004p000000) and then [publish them as services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Example_Publish_a_map_service_from_a_map_document_MXD/0154000005qr000000/). Quite doable, but lots of work yet easy to do.

**3** You take your service .mxd docs and publish them with arcpy as services (if needed, with modified data source path). Thereafter, you change services' properties by reading corresponding services on the dev machine (#instances, pooling, capabilities, permissions etc.). This is done by using the [ArcGIS Server Administrator API scripting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Scripting_with_the_ArcGIS_Server_Administrator_API/0154000005r1000000/). There are many samples that will help list the service properties and then apply them to the corresponding services.

From my experience, the 3rd alternative is the best.

Comment: in the second approach how can we keep the service name the same as to the previous one. Because in the script of publishing the map service that you have provided in the link define the service name= USA.